# Error while trying to log into Mediawiki through curl

Tags: python, authentication, curl, http-post, mediawiki

I am trying to log into a mediawiki page through curl to check the content remotely:

My curl request is this one:

```
curl --insecure -d action=login -d lgname=myuser -d lgpassword=mypwd -d format=json https://mediawiki.example.com
```

The command returns this:

```
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
```

I also tried including my credentials in the url:

```
curl https://mediawiki.example.com/w/api.php?action=login&format=json&lgname=user&lgpassword=mypwd
```

But it didnt worked...

I also tried what I saw in the [documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:XZise/Login_with_cURL)

```
curl -k -b cookie.lwp -c cookie.lwp -d action=login -d lgname=user -d lgpassword=mypwd -d format=json https://mediawiki.example.com
```

But I still receive unauthorized...

When I copy as a curl the request I do into the browser, I obtain this, and it works:

```
curl -k 'https://mediawiki.example.com/index.php/My_Search' \
  -H 'authority: mediawiki.example.com' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'accept-language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  -H 'authorization: Basic cnR4OTc3NzpLcm9uaXN0MTExMQ==' \
  -H 'cache-control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'cookie: wikiUserName=user; wiki_session=xxxxxxxxx; wikiUserID=14' \
  -H 'referer: https://mediawiki.example.com/index.php?title=Especial:Entrar&returnto=My+Search' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --compressed
```

But it only works for some minutes...

I also tried with this script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3

"""
    login.py

    MediaWiki API Demos
    Demo of `Login` module: Sending post request to login
    MIT license
"""

import requests

S = requests.Session()

URL = "https://mediawiki.example.com/"

# Retrieve login token first
PARAMS_0 = {
    'action':"query",
    'meta':"tokens",
    'type':"login",
    'format':"json"
}

R = S.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS_0)
DATA = R.json()

LOGIN_TOKEN = DATA['query']['tokens']['logintoken']

print(LOGIN_TOKEN)

# Send a post request to login. Using the main account for login is not
# supported. Obtain credentials via Special:BotPasswords
# (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:BotPasswords) for lgname & lgpassword

PARAMS_1 = {
    'action':"login",
    'lgname':"user",
    'lgpassword':"mypwd",
    'lgtoken':LOGIN_TOKEN,
    'format':"json"
}

R = S.post(URL, data=PARAMS_1)
DATA = R.json()

print(DATA)
```

But I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loginmedia.py", line 25, in <module>
    R = S.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS_0)
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mediawiki.example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /wiki?action=query&meta=tokens&type=login&format=json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)'),))
```

Comment: You are probably using the wrong URL for `api.php`. Try opening it in the browser, if it works, you should see API documentation.

Comment: And you do need the extra arguments you saw in the documentation.

Comment: @Tgr So the extra argument is the session, but how can I obtain it?